# Как получить историю логов js

Tags: javascript

Код сайта по "Посмотреть код" недоступен. Но мне нужно чтобы пользователь по нажатию на кнопку получил все логи которые были записаны js. Весь интернет перелазил не нашел ответа на мой вопрос.

Comment: о каких логах речь?

Comment: О тех которые записываются в консоль браузера. console.log() console.warn() и console.error()

Comment: таки логируй данные в файл/localStorage/БД/любоеДругоеХранилище и потом отдавай по требованию

Comment: Попробую, спасибо.

Comment: Ты что, с телефона их смотреть хочешь?

Comment: PROPHESSOR, нет. И вы видимо мой вопрос невнимательно прочитали.

Comment: @Doc-com в таком случае, лучше сделать вопрос более подробным и однозначным ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
const logs = []; //Место для хранения логов
const clog = console.log.bind(console); //Сохраняем console.log
console.log = (...args) => { //Заменяем console.log на нашу функцию
    logs.push(args.toString()); //Записываем в logs
    clog(args.toString()); //Вызываем оригинальный console.log
}
//Теперь при нажатии на кнопку можно вывести logs в удобном формате
```

Comment: то же самое можно провернуть и с warn, info, error, etc

Comment: Такое себе решение. Во первых `logs` нужно сделать `const`. Во вторых `toString`и убрать, т.к. невозможно передать объекты и массивы. В третьих это сработает только для мажорных браузеров. Сомневаюсь что какой-нибудь ие поймет spread и arrow functions. Ну и переопределять нативные функции моветон. Не проще ли завести враппер для console.log и использовать его?

Comment: @Herrgott let изменил. Если не убрать toString - будет записываться массив аргументов, что в одной ситуации удобно, а в другой нет. Я дал решение. А люди пусть делают под себя... P.S> то же и на счёт ES6

Comment: clog не всегда будет работать, нужно забиндить: `clog = console.log.bind(console)`

Comment: @vp_arth исправил